# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '–20'

Tags: python

Taking input from user, dividing into lists shown in below;

```
input=addi $sp, $sp, –20'

registers=['$sp', '$sp', '–20']
```

then convert it into binary that `-20` by

```
x=int(registers[2])
def dec2bin(x):
n= int(x)
m = n + 1 if n < 0 else n
bitlen = 1 + m.bit_length()
mask = (1 << bitlen) - 1
return '{0:0{1}b}'.format(n & mask, 16)
```

Code is working with `addi $sp, $sp, 20` but somehow it can't convert the `-20` to the integer and giving the error as

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '–20'

Comment: Replace `–` by `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several similar-looking dash characters, such as —, –, -. The one that integer parsers usually expect you to use is `-`, the ASCII hyphen-minus.

You can replace the wrong dash in your string with the correct minus using

```
replace('–', '-')
```